# Is there an easier way to do this problem without using so many if statements? and how?

Tags: if-statement, printing, count, state, fsm

We were given a problem that asks to use the letters QDN(Quarter, Dime, Nickel) to create a finite state machine that only accepts if they add to 40 cents. I have the basics down for using an IF statement concept. I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this that takes less time?

I've tried making tons of if cases but there are a lot of steps to using that method.

```
public class FSA2_rpf4961 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //The program will read in a sequence of strings and test them against a 
    //FSM. Your strings may not contain blank spaces
    System.out.println("Enter string to test or q to terminate");
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String testString = in.next();

    while (!testString.equals("q"))
    {
        String testOutput = applyFSA2(testString);
        System.out.println("For the test string "+testString+
                                ", the FSM output is "+testOutput);
        System.out.println("Enter next string to test or q to terminate:");
        testString = in.next();

    }
    in.close();

}
public static String applyFSA(String s) {
   String currentOut = "0";                // initial output in s0
   String currentState = "s0";             // initial state

   int i = 0;

   while (i<s.length())
   {
            //quarter first
           if (currentState.equals("s0") && s.charAt(i) == 'q')
           {
                    currentState = "s1";  
                    currentOut += 25;  // collect output on move to s1
           }
           else if (currentState.equals("s1") && s.charAt(i)  == 'd') {
            currentState = "s2";
            currentOut += 10;
           }
           else if (currentState.equals("s2") && s.charAt(i)  == 'n') {
            currentState = "s3";
            currentOut += 5;
           }
           else if (currentState.equals("s1") && s.charAt(i)  == 'n') {
            currentState = "s4";
            currentOut += 5;
           }
           else if (currentState.equals("s4") && s.charAt(i)  == 'd') {
            currentState = "s3";
            currentOut += 10;
           }

           //dime first
           else if (currentState.equals("s0") && s.charAt(i) == 'd')
           {
                    currentState = "s5";
                    currentOut += 10;   // d
            }
```

We need it to only accept if it adds to 40 cents. This is very confusing for me to grasp.

Comment: There is no test for 40 cents and no message to reject when not 40 cents.  Also currentState seems un-necessary, as there is no requirement that they be in ascending order.  In the While, just test s.charAt(i) for q or d or n and add appropriate value.  Also, convert each input to lowercase when comparing.  Also, q should not equal both Quit and Quarter -- use x for Exit...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be talking generally here, because your current code is weird to the point of almost-certain brokenness. I don't quite get what your "output" is supposed to be.

A FSM is a definition of a set of states and how input causes state transitions. It looks like you started out roughly doing that, but `currentOut` is broken.
If your goal was to get a sum, you're defeating the entire point of the exercise. It doesn't matter what the sum is. What matters is what state you're in at the end -- particularly whether you're in an "accept" state, which in this case is the state where the string equates to exactly 40 cents.

As for how to implement a FSM without kajillions of `if`s, you can often store states in an array, and have your state name be a state number instead. At that point, you can theoretically get rid of *all* your `if`s. (In the real world, though, you'd probably still want one to ignore or reject chars other than (q|d|n).)

Consider something like this (pseudocode):

```
    // Each array in `graph` represents a state.
    // Each entry is the state number (ie: index into `graph`) to go to
    // when you're in that state and see the corresponding char.
    //
    // BTW, the state graph makes a lot more sense when you consider nickels first.
    // A nickel takes you to the "next" state, and dimes and quarters act like
    // 2 and 5 nickels, respectively. When you do that, a pattern shows up.
    graph = [
      //  n  d  q
      //-----------
        [ 1, 2, 5 ], // s0
        [ 2, 3, 6 ], // s1
        [ 3, 4, 7 ], // s2
        [ 4, 5, 8 ], // s3
        [ 5, 6, 9 ], // s4
        [ 6, 7, 9 ], // s5
        [ 7, 8, 9 ], // s6
        [ 8, 9, 9 ], // s7
        [ 9, 9, 9 ], // s8
        [ 9, 9, 9 ]  // s9 (fail state)
    ]
    start = 0
    accept = 8
    fail = 9

    // at this point, walking the graph is trivial.
    state = start
    for each char c in s:
        index = "ndq".indexOf(c) // n->0, d->1, q->2, others -> -1
        state = graph[state][index]


    // Once the loop's done:
    //   if state == accept, you have exactly 40c.
    //   if state == fail, you have >40c. A FSM won't tell you how much,
    //      because FSMs can't count.
    // any other state represents a known amount that's less than 40c.
```